# Facebook scores cant be deleted due to removed permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

again a little question considering facebook scores. As the app-admin I am able to set and delete scores for certain users with the app-accesstoken, lets say in case of cheating. I tried around a little and came to notice, that once a user removes the "publish_actions" permission, he seems to be able to block any access from me, the app-admin. It only returns an error considering the missing permission when I try to post / delete the score with the app-accesstoken.

I MUST be doing something wrong here, right?! A cheater could not get away that simple or is he?!?! Cheating its way to the top of the leaderboard and then just removing the "publish_actions" permission via the app settings? XD